# How does one find the total number of close votes a user has cast?

Tags: feature-request

Is there a way to find out the number of close votes a user has cast in total? There is a query here, but does not work for me. A similar query for delete votes is also helpful.

http://data.stackexchange.com/english/query/171204/my-total-close-votes

Answer (score 2):

You can find out how many close votes you have cast from your profile:

[image: 3 steps to finding your close votes]

1. Select the votes tab in your profile. It's the furthest tab to the right.
2. Select the colsure sub-tab. It's second from the right.
3. The count of your close votes is shown on the far left.

This doesn't include deleted questions (as far as I know) but nor would using the data explorer. The data explorer doesn't have data about deleted questions.

The list of delete votes you've cast is in the middle of the sub tabs.

Comment: Thanks Matt. Is there a way to get this data for other users?

Comment: Not using this method. There might be a way in the data explorer.

Comment: In the spirit of transparency, I will admit here that my total votes to date are **delete**:30, **undelete**:2, **close**:3556, **reopen**:100. I don't know why SE doesn't let you see these *particular* values for other users, when it *does* show you separate values for their **up** and **down** votes, and how many (up *or* down) votes they cast for questions and for answers. Perhaps there's some logic being this behaviour, but perhaps TPTB just never got around to making the relevant code changes.

Comment: @Bravo: No, there is no way to track Close Votes on users that are not you. You *can* track total [upvotes and downvotes](http://data.stackexchange.com/english/query/186716/top-downvoters) and you can note which users Favorite which posts but that's about it.